# Can a texbox click event be captured?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Sorry to bother you again on this problem.

The solution I accepted from James Johnson didn't actually work because, it prevents me from entering any data into the textbox which is not what we want.

We would like to diplays the message as a help info only. In other words, we would just like to advise the the user to tick the checkbox if s/he wishes to receive an email.

Below is what I have come up with based on the reference hel from Rob.
This works. The only assistance I would like to get your help on is to get the message to open up in a a new window. THe sample message I am using is Focus Fire.

Can you please help?

THis is the latest code:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">span id='1' {display:none;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryMsg.js"></script>
</head>
<asp:TextBox ID="chck1" runat="server" Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
<span id='1'>focus fire</span>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = (function () { 
try{    $("input:text").focus(function () {               
$(this).next("span").css('display','inline').fadeOut(1000);    });            
}catch(e){}});</script>
```

Comment: its possible. what have you tried?

Comment: You said first "Can a texbox be moused over?" then later asked "as soon as a user **clicks** on the textbox", which is it? There are a bunch of events: onClick, onHover, onFocus...

Comment: Hi Chad, I am sorry as I might be mixing things up. we would like an ability to give a user an instruction as soon as the user clicks a textbox to enter text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the textbox in a SPAN, and add a `onmouseover` event to the span.

```
<span onmouseover="alert('This is a TextBox');"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span>
```

Comment: Hi James, your solution is the most promising so far simply because of it's ease of use. I am trying to style it to get close to the checkbox. It is just way too far away from the textbox. THanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the `ClientIDMode`-attribute to you text box so that JavaScript can access it via the ID without fiddling with the ctrwhateverstrangeidaspnetproduces:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="instruct" runat="server" Width="75px" ClientIDMode="static">
```

And then handle the Click-Event (this example is using jQuery, you can use raw JavaScript as well):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#instruct').click(function() {
        alert('.click()-handler called.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dennis. On this line, alert('.click()-handler called.'); is this where I put inx on structions like "Please check box on right if you wish to receive confirmation? I am very new to javascript.

Comment: Yes, the alert function can be replaced by any javascript code. As long as it's inside the function, it gets executed whenever the control gets clicked.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add it in your codebehind in the Page Load event such as:

instruct.Attributes.Add("onclick", "yourJavascriptFunction();")

The reason for adding in the Page Load event is added Attributes are lost during postback.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the onFocus() event handler for JavaScript which will execute a provided function when focusing on the desired textbox, as this method will work if the user clicks or tabs to the desired textbox.

Or you can use [focus()](http://jqapi.com/#p=focus) in jQuery:

```
$('#instruct').focus(function(){
    // Insert desired response here
    alert('Your instructions');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, we would prefer that it not have focus. The reason is we are using simply as instruction, not to validate anything.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the onFocus event instead (in case the user tabs to the textarea instead of clicking on it, I'm assuming you want to display your message then as well):

```
$('textarea').focus(function(){
    alert('hi');
}):
```

Comment: Thanks alex. The only thing still confusingme is whether that's all Do I need to do more?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time and unbelievable assistance. The only way I can understand, and I am able to use is one from James Johnson. Again, thank you experts for your assistance.